# What's a good Rails CMS engine for customization of existing app views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, content-management-system

I have this project almost finished using Rails 4, Bootstrap 3 and Devise, but there's many content the client will need to change/update, so I'm in need of a lightweight non-instrusive CMS to co-work with my existing application.

I came across some Rails CMS available, mainly Refinery, Locomotive, Casein, adva, BrowserCMS but I'm not sure about any of them, some of them aren't updated since 2011/2013 (adva and BrowserCMS respectively), and some lacks support/documentation (I really liked Casein but couldn't find great information about it). I couldn't have a taste of Locomotive and Refinery, but both of them seems to be too much for what I need. Refinery has mixed reviews, some people love it, but other people seems to have a lot of trouble with it - specially with already existing app using Devise, and learning curve (I have few days to get this working).

Also, I'm not very familiar with CMSs, specially on Rails, but what I need is something that allows me to specify what portions of existing views can be edited by the admin (actually no need for creating other views/sections/pages), a CRUD for some models would be very handy, and a separate admins' system (as my user's system are intended to website visitors, not admins).

Can I have some advise on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Being between crossfire can be annoying as regards choosing what will be, and what will not be when it comes to coding. You should give your choices a try and choose what you think is best for your work

**My advice**

1. **RefineryCMS**
   RefineryCMS is update to support Rails 4.2 and its updated often, even like 3 days ago. You can see RefineryCMS Guide below to put you on track.

   [Refinery Guide](http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started)

**Note:** 

 1. 
To get familier with Rails CRUD action, you can use [Lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Basic-CRUD/139989/159111-4.html) Kevin Skoglund tutorails to get familier with Rails CMS which was based on CRUD actions.

 2. 
You can also see Railscasts Tutorials by Ryan Bates. You will learn more about how cool Refinery can be.

Thanks.